# deploying a contract private key error

Tags: contract-development, private-key, python

I am following  tutorial entitled "DApp Development for Python Programmers" by levelup.gitconnected.  The url is https://levelup.gitconnected.com/dapps-development-for-python-developers-f52b32b54f28.  In this tutorial there is a python file entitled deploy.py it looks like

```
*deploy.py
import json
from web3 import Web3, HTTPProvider
from web3.contract import ConciseContract

# web3.py instance
w3 = Web3(HTTPProvider("https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/<API key>"))
print(w3.isConnected())

key="<Private Key here with 0x prefix>"
acct = w3.eth.account.privateKeyToAccount(key)

# compile your smart contract with truffle first
truffleFile = json.load(open('./build/contracts/greeter.json'))
abi = truffleFile['abi']
bytecode = truffleFile['bytecode']
contract= w3.eth.contract(bytecode=bytecode, abi=abi)

#building transaction
construct_txn = contract.constructor().buildTransaction({
    'from': acct.address,
    'nonce': w3.eth.getTransactionCount(acct.address),
    'gas': 1728712,
    'gasPrice': w3.toWei('21', 'gwei')})

signed = acct.signTransaction(construct_txn)

tx_hash=w3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed.rawTransaction)
print(tx_hash.hex())
tx_receipt = w3.eth.waitForTransactionReceipt(tx_hash)
print("Contract Deployed At:", tx_receipt['contractAddress'])
```

On line 10 (key="<Private Key here with 0x prefix>") when I enter my secret key I with the 0x prefix get an error message posted below:

> ValueError: The private key must be exactly 32 bytes long, instead of
> 34 bytes

I tried it without the 0x prefix and I get the error:

> ValueError: The private key must be exactly 32 bytes long, instead of
> 32 bytes.

What am I missing?  Thank You in advance.

Comment: There may be Spaces

Comment: Hi BejaminHall! Welcome to Ethereum Stackexchange! Please include the code as text, it makes it easier to test.

Comment: Sorry about that...I change the image for text now.

Comment: @zmy:  Are you referring to "Spaces" as appearances of white space characters in my private key string? Because there are none.

Comment: Heck, that's a weird question

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue a while back. This error most likely results from accidentally using the Infura "project secret" as the private key when you should use an ETH and LINK funded wallet private key. Make sure to [get test ETH and LINK tokens](https://docs.chain.link/docs/link-token-contracts/) into the wallet first.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue while confusing the private key with other keys and addresses.  Using MetaMask, the correct private key can be found under "Account details > Export Private Key".

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your testurl from Infura is on the network that you're using, I.E: ropsten.

Answer (score 0):

NGL, I ran into this issue and it took me a few minutes to realize that I was calling the run scripts from the wrong directory...